# How to block a users name from getting mail using postfix

Tags: postfix, users, filter

I have a setup where I use /etc/aliases to define several email addresses for a user, e.g.:
foo:     user
bar:     user
foo.bar: user

However I want to block the users name (user@domain.com) from getting email (due to spam) while keeping the aliases valid.
Any hints how to do this with minimal effort and minimal side effects on other users email?

Thanks in advance.